# Webpack re executing entry point scripts when dynamic imports are present

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

This stated to happen after my project's webpack was updated from 1.x to 2.6.0. We have a legacy IIFE script called asyncModules, which does a querySelectorAll for nodes with data-module attribute, those must have the same name as one of the modules in the asyncModules directory. It uses require.ensure then a dynamic require() with the name of the data-module attribute.

Someone noticed that after updating it's being called multiple times. It seems like after all the requires are done, it executes the script again (I've debugged by printing on console, seen it happen up to 3 times). I tried using webpack 2's import(), but the same issue happens. I tried importing it directly from the main entry point script (same as it was before updating), including the offending script directly into the entrypoint bundle, adding it to the vendor bundle, all still have the same issue. It only stops happening if I completely remove the dynamic requires from that file, then my log shows it only running once (the way it should be).

I've triple checked the code for duplicate calls to that file, none found, and if it was the case, disabling the requires should still result in multiple executions, which is not the case.

I'm using babel with es215 set to modules: false.

```js
const moduleElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-module]')

console.log('asyncModules') //This is how I checked it being executed more than once

for (var i = 0; i < moduleElements.length; i++) {
  const el = moduleElements[i]
  const name = el.getAttribute('data-module')
  require.ensure([], function() {
    const Module = require(`./${name}/index`).default
    new Module(el)
  })
}
```

Comment: `require.ensure` was replaced in favour of `import` in new webpack releases.\

Comment: Yes, and as I said, import().then() still causes the same problem

Comment: I tried and it works as expected, please provide a github repository with a minimal and reproducible case. Did you already check if there are dom nodes which ask for the same module?